# error when using browserify with a module written in coffeescript

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, browserify

I'm trying to use browserify to bundle a script I've made which depends on the "sparql" node module. When I run `browserify` I get the following error

```
Error: Cannot find module './lib/sparql' from '~/scta-statistics/node_modules/sparql'
```

I think i'm getting this error because when I look at the directory `~/scta-statistics/node_modules/sparql/lib/` I don't see 'sparql' but rather `sparql.coffee'.

So how can I tell browserify to correctly bundle this module??

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You will probably want to use the coffeeify transform: https://github.com/jnordberg/coffeeify